# Getting value of ListView TextView

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have this ListView setup:

```
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long id) {

                //

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Rate.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Items.this, R.layout.list,
                items));
```

It is a standard ListView as you see.  Each row has a single TextView populated with the List "items". I am pulling that in from a MySQL Database and outputting through a JSON loop.

I simply want to be able to click on the row, with its single name, and take that name and pass it into the Rate.class activity as a String.  How can I do this in code?

Answer (score 2):

Add putExtra to your intent (see below). I am assuming you have the list 'items' as the member of the activity, the arg2 argument is basically the index of the item clicked in the list, which you can use to get the name from the 'items' list.

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long id) {

            //

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Rate.class);
            i.putExtra("name", items.get(arg2));
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Comment: Perfect!  I didn't realize arg2 was the index and can be turned into a String.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a specific array adapter instance instead of just creating one to pass to the function.  Then in the `OnItemClick()` function, int arg2 is the index in the array adapter that the user selected.  You can get the view from the array adapter and getText() from the text view.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things passed to onItemClick is the view that was clicked:

Cast view to the appropriate type and call `getText()` on it; for example:

```
final String text = ((TextView)view).getText();
```